# Where can I hear the trapped sounds inside a pulsar?

Tags: acoustics, resource-recommendations, astronomy, data, pulsars

I have been searching for an audible track of stellar oscillations inside a pulsar, but I don't seem to find what I want. No, I am not asking about the radio waves emitted that have been converted into audible sound. I'm asking about the trapped sound inside a pulsar. My questions relates to Asteroseismology, if that could help.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/566114/226902

Answer (score 1):

We can detect the radio beam from pulsars (and even optical or X-rays from X-ray pulsars) but so far we have no observations about [oscillation modes of neutron stars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutron-star_oscillation). We have no electromagnetic counterpart of such oscillations, apart from (but this is speculative) the so-called quasi-periodic oscillations observed in the soft-gamma after a magnetar burst (these oscillations may be linked to the elastic modes of the solid crust of the magnetar, e.g. see [this article](https://arxiv.org/abs/1708.05702) ). Unfortunately we have very few observations of this kind and all this is speculative: so far we observed the following QPO (quasi-periodic oscillations)

Confirmed QPO frequencies:

SGR 1806-20: 18, 26, 30, 92
150, 625, 1840 Hz

SGR 1900+14: 28, 53, 84,
155 Hz

where SGR stands for [Short Gamma Repeater](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_gamma_repeater). Clearly magneto-elastic oscillations in the solid crust may be excited by such violent magnetar  bursts but are not the only candidate mechanism to explain QPOs.

Of course certain oscillation modes may be sources of gravitational waves but still, we are unable to detect them.
Since we can not detect in any way (electromagnetically or gravitationally) the "seismic sound" of neutron stars, we can not convert it into "traditional sound".